# How to capture packet from multiple interface using dumpcap

Tags: linux

Capture packet from multiple interface using dumpcap not working:

```
dumpcap -i eth2 eth1 eth3
```

It didn't work as well.

Regards
Rohit

Comment: Refer the dumpcap man page. http://linux.die.net/man/1/dumpcap

Answer (score 5):

Please try

```
dumpcap -i eth2 -i eth1 -i eth3
```

I hope this will work.

Regards,
Ankit